# Composite web application without frames

Tags: java, web, menu, frames, composite

I have built two web applications lets call them App1 and App2.

App1 has multiple pages (Page1.jsp and Page2.jsp). App1 is a standalone application which has a menu which links to the two pages.

App2 has multiple pages (Page3.jsp and Page4.jsp). App2 is also a standalone application which has a menu which links to the two pages.

Now I would like to combine App1 and App2 into a super-application without modifying App1 or App2. This super-application should have a menu which links to App1/Page1.jsp, App1/Page2.jsp, App2/Page3.jsp, and App2/Page4.jsp.

I think of a couple of approaches to doing this:

**Solution 1: Frames**

I can create a menu frame which has a menu which links to the pages of App1 and App2.

I can have a seperate frame which is used to display the content for App1 and App2.

However, I am not keen to use frames (http://www.html-faq.com/htmlframes/?framesareevil).

**Solution 2: Dynamically build the menu based on URL parameter**

Super application can have a div-based menu which links to App1 and App2. It can pass a parameter on the URL, e.g. App1/Page1.jsp?parent=SuperApp.

App1 and App2 can dynamically build a menu based on the parent parameter.

For example, if the parent parameter is not present then App1 will use its normal menu which links to Page1.jsp and Page2.jsp.

However, if the parent parameter is present then App1 will use the SuperApp menu (SuperApp/header.html) - it will dynamically include this HTML in the JSP page. This SuperApp menu will link to all the pages provided in App1 and App2.

This second solution will work without using frames, but I wanted to explore if there are other solutions I haven't considered?

Comment: Why don't you simply make one, well-integrated application? It wouldn't be as messy.

Comment: I'd like to have App1 and App2 as standalone applications - there are situations I'd like to deploy App1 without App2, and situations I would like to deploy App2 without App1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about having a third web application responsible for menus:

[image]

Configure a very small JavaScript component in each page that makes an AJAX call to the menu application to populate it. Typically this would be implemented with an empty `<div>` with a special class or ID. You also have a script (downloaded from MenuApp) that locates the `<div>` and adds the menu.

Some ideas:

- Simplest implementation is that the MenuApp uses servlet config to configure menu options. A more flexible approach could use a SQL or NoSQL DB
- Parameterized call, where the calling page could call in with a menu context (eg LoggedIn, AdvancedUser, Configuration) and the MenuApp returns an appropriate subset of menu items
- Even more advanced: The user can configure their own favorites

The main disadvantage with this is the additional callback, although if you are already using AJAX this might be a very low overhead.

BTW, this is similar to how FaceBook, Google+, Twitter, Pinterest, etc implement their Like, PlusOne, etc, buttons, while being minimally invasive in the third-party web application. Eg see: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use portlets when you want to use two applications together. Deployment will be the same, you don't need to make any changes in App1 and App2. Depending on which portlet container you would like to use, configuration is different, but finally you will have one portlet for each application and configure menu of that portal to target urls of each application.

Two possible solutions are [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) and [Jetspeed](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/). With thous two I worked. Also there is JBoss [GateIn](http://www.jboss.org/gatein/portletcontainer.html) portlet container.